# Increase access token time in GCP UI or via python API

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, metadata, service-accounts, google-apis-explorer

I am using VM enabled on GCP and would like to increase access token time. By default it is 1 hour.

I a using below command to generate token

```
query = "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token"
response = requests.get(query,headers={"Metadata-Flavor": "Google"}).json()
```

It generates token in the following format and it shows the 'expires_in' seconds. This is remaining time for the token to expire.

```
{'access_token': 'ya29.c.Ko8BEAjJKLI1bUQBiIj0zZz5hw3TlLjyCoXxKtyslbEnyRj9eUWO0sVdW3512f64ynOoi6laZNnPV
O23nELV5fYhk2epYodI1kXXXXXXXXXXX', 'expires_in': 3035, 'token_type': 'Bearer'}
```

How can I increase the expires_in parameters either through UI, configuration file or Python API such that token expire as per the defined time?

The purpose of creating long lived token is as I am starting TPU from Google VM using TPU start API and TPU turns on and my machine learning model is trained on the TPU. ML models are quite complex and take more than 10 or 20 hours in many scenarios. After the computations is over on the TPU I want TPU to shut down itself. Then I get the above error which says it cannot authenticated the token as it is expired.

Any example / way to increase the token expiry time or some other way to get rid of this problem.

Comment: The quick answer is that you cannot via the metadata server. However, there are other solutions that might be possible. Is your project part of an Organization? If yes, see @guillaume's answer. Do you actually require long-term OAuth Tokens? Edit your question with details.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do that with the metadata server. However, it's possible to generate a short lived token and to extend up to 12h the lifetime of the access token.

You can have a look at [this Service Account Credential API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateAccessToken#request-body). However, you need to update the organisation policy to extend the default (60min) lifetime duration.

Comment: I looked into the link. I logged with my gcloud account and set the role of service account token creator as per roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator. It asks name and I defined it as  projects/-/serviceAccounts/{ACCOUNT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUEID}. The - wildcard character is required; replacing it with a project ID is invalid. What is the wildcard in this? I write project name as projec* but it give 400 error.

Comment: Yes, you need to keep the - wildcard. It's a global resource, you can find similar thing with CLoud Storage for example.

Comment: my project name is say "projectname" and I am giving project* .   My name variable is "projects/project*/serviceAccounts/213310257965-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" and passing   { scope": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"
  ] } as request parameter. I am getting 400 error. I am not able to make out what mistake I am making.

Comment: The API documentation state this: ` The - wildcard character is required; replacing it with a project ID is invalid.` Don't put your project name, put the dash